# How can get the variable name from a Java interface if I Know the value?

Tags: java, selenium, reflection, interface

I have a Java interface like this:

```
String User_Name= "username";
String User_Password="password";
```

Inside to a different class, I want to get the variable Name when I know the value. For example I know the "username" and I want to find in which variable this value is stored. I am expecting to get the User_Name.
Is this possible with reflection?

Comment: Why on earth would you need to do that? Do you have a use case for it?

Comment: I am using JBehave with Selenium. So in stories when user writes gives something like: When enter 'username' as 'admin'.  The 'username' is the name of the webElement. I have created an interface and i have stored the name of the Element inside the User_Name in order to be more readable and in a central location (object repository). However stories cannot implement Interface. So I am parsing always in step definition class text and not variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use reflection to iterate through all fields and check the values. This should serve as a basic example:

```
for (Field field : obj.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
    if(field.get(obj) == desired_value)
           System.out.println("The matching field is " + field.getName());
    System.out.println(field.getName()
             + " - " + field.getType()
             + " - " + field.get(obj));

}
```